# Port becomes unreachable even the service is running

Tags: linux, linux-networking, jenkins

I am running Jenkins on default 8080. The service is monitored on port. I occasionally get an alert of "Unreachable port 8080". When ssh'd to server, "netstat" shows port is use and "ps -aux" shows the service is running.
When restarted the service, the issue gets resolved.
But how is this possible that a port is unreachable, without any firewall, while a service is running on that port. 
Checking the log of service, I got this

```
INFO: Social-Cron-to-check-gnip-limit #439246 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:04 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
WARNING: Parameter handlerCountMax is now deprecated
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:04 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
WARNING: Parameter handlerCountMaxIdle is now deprecated
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:04 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @851ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:05 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:05 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:05 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2018-08-30T13:59:14.071Z; git: 272086856853232186989f695db2d7b21ebc51; jvm 1.8.0_171-b10
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:06 AM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:06 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:06 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:06 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: SystemProperties.getProperty("JENKINS_HOME")
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:08 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@2e570ded{Jenkins v2.156,/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:08 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@3cfdd820{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:08 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @4675ms
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:08 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:11 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:11 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:18 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:18 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:21 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:21 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 3 ms
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2652a0c2: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Jun 11 04:42:22 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2652a0c2]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@354c4643
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@354c4643: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2e78e11d: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Jun 11 04:42:22 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2e78e11d]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6f749996
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6f749676: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:23 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:23 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:23 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: campaign_drip_cron #38917 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jun 11, 2019 4:42:43 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.JobCollector getNamespace
INFO: The prometheus namespace is now [default]
Jun 11, 2019 4:43:01 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: campaign_summary_cron #38630 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jun 11, 2019 4:43:01 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: campaign_drip_cron #38918 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jun 11, 2019 4:43:01 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: campaign_sms_cron #38676 main build action completed: SUCCESS
Jun 11, 2019 4:43:01 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: campaign_SMS_DND #38658 main build action completed: SUCCESS
```

and so on and the service restarts without any error or mentioning anything. I am clueless why is this happening and what to do.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running Jenkins v2.156. The current LTS version of Jenkins is 2.176.1, the weekly build is even on 2.180. I'd suggest you update Jenkins first, to rule out bugs that have already been resolved.

Comment: What do you get when you try access the WebUI after you get that alert?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Couldn't update the version. Most unlikely but if that is the issue, we will consider it at last after covering all other and also, the change-log of Jenkins 2.176 does not shows any issue of this kind.

Comment: Check the logs of the monitoring host. `Unreachable port 8080` could just be caused by a temporary network problem between monitoring host and Jenkins. You might want to add a ping check to rule out networking problems. If temporary network problems are the cause you might want to add a rule to only throw an alarm only if the check fails several times in a row.

Comment: @bhavicp The monitoring has action attached on trigger to restart the service as trigger is in PROBLEM. It takes around 1-2 mins. In between, the webUI keeps loading and then shows jenkins loading page. In case of removing the action trigger, I think it would give a TIMEOUT ERROR